# How long should a weighted average take on Apache Ignite?

Tags: real-time, benchmarking, in-memory-database, fork-join, ignite

I am currently benchmarking Appache Ignite for a near real-time application and simple operations seem to be excessively slow for a relatively small sample size. **The following is giving the setup details and timings - please see 2 questions at the bottom.**

Setup:

- Cache mode: Partitioned
- Number of server nodes: 3
- CPUs: 4 per node (12)
- Heap size: 2GB per node (6GB)

The first use case is computing the weighted average over two fields of the object at different rates.

First method is to run a SQL style query:

```
...
query = new SqlFieldsQuery("select SUM(field1*field2)/SUM(field2) from MyObject");
cache.query(query).getAll();
....
```

The observed timings are:

Cache: 500,000  Queries/second: 10
Median: 428ms, 90th percentile: 13,929ms

Cache: 500,000  Queries/second: 50
Median: 191,465ms, 90th percentile: 402,285ms

Clearly this is queuing up with an enormous latency (>400 ms), a simple weighted average computation on a single jvm (4 Cores) takes 6 ms.

The second approach is to use the IgniteCompute to broadcast Callables across nodes and compute the weighted average on each node, reducing at the caller, latency is only marginally better, throughput improves but still at unusable levels.

Cache: 500,000  Queries/second: 10
Median: 408ms, 90th percentile: 507ms

Cache: 500,000  Queries/second: 50
Median: 114,155ms, 90th percentile: 237,521ms

A few things i noticed during the experiment:

- No disk swapping is happening
- CPUs run at up to 400%
- Query is split up in two different weighted averages (map reduce)
- Entries are evenly split across the nodes
- No garbage collections are triggered with each heap size around 500MB

To my questions:

1. **Are these timings expected or is there some obvious setting i am missing? I could not find benchmarks on similar operations.**
2. **What is the advised method to run fork-join style computations on ignite without moving data?**

Answer (score 0):

This topic was discussed in detail on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-performance-td6703.html